# add custom jar to maven local repository

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to add a custom jar to my Project. As I understand it the best way to do that is to first add the jar to my local repository and then to add it to my pom.xml.

So I tried the following:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/martin/linuxhome/work/libMediator/libMediator
 /dist/libMediator.jar -DgroupId=com.src.libMediator -DartifactId=libMediator 
 Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

and then I added the following to my pom.xml:

```
...
<packaging>war</packaging>
...
<dependencies>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.src.libMediator</groupId>
    <artifactId>libMediator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                             
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Reportgenerator 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for joda-time:joda-time-jsptags:jar:1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Reportgenerator ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Copying 26 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Reportgenerator ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 21 source files to /home/martin/linuxhome/Dropbox/c/Reportgenerator/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/martin/linuxhome/Dropbox/c/Reportgenerator/src/main/resources/boilerplate/ReportIdentifizierer.java:[8,32] package com.src.libMediator.prod does not exist
[ERROR] /home/martin/linuxhome/Dropbox/c/Reportgenerator/src/main/resources/boilerplate/ReportIdentifizierer.java:[30,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable C_ProdUtility
  location: class boilerplate.ReportIdentifizierer
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.116s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 07 15:30:50 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/169M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Reportgenerator: Compilation failure:     Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/martin/linuxhome/Dropbox/c/Reportgenerator/src/main/resources/boilerplate/ReportIdentifizierer.java:[8,32] package com.src.libMediator.prod does not exist
[ERROR] /home/martin/linuxhome/Dropbox/c/Reportgenerator/src/main/resources/boilerplate/ReportIdentifizierer.java:[30,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable C_ProdUtility
[ERROR] location: class boilerplate.ReportIdentifizierer
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

C_ProdUtility is a class from the jar I want to include, boilerplate.ReportIdentifizierer is a class which belongs to the Project I am working on.

I have tried to google the problem, but none of the solutions I found worked. I could use the System Scope and give the location of the jar via

```
<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/libMediator.jar</systemPath>
```

. Then it compiles but this is discouraged and the jar isn't provided at runtime. I haven't found out how to do that.

If I use

compile

The resulting .war gives the following error-message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.src.libMediator.prod.C_ProdUtility from [Module "deployment.Reportgenerator.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

I verified that com.src.libMediator.prod.C_ProdUtility is in the libMediator.jar

Comment: If the jar content is needed for compilation, the jar's scope is obviously not `runtime`, don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

By doing this you change scope to compile.
Check how scopes work in [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) if you are interested in details.